# Updating web.config revert previous updates

Tags: asp.net, wss, wss-3.0

I've a SPJob Scheduled with a package (wsp) installation which update web.config and a Application Page which also build to update web.config.

The problem is when I install the package it successfully update the web.config. I've confirmed the changes. Now, when we go to our Application Page which also successfully update the web.config but I lost the changes made during package installation.

Any idea what would I be doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you developing this package installation? If so, how are you editing the file? Are you saving changes and then closing the file properly?

If not, is this SPTimerJob going to be a regular occurence? Have you tried changing the web.config manually and opening the Application Page to see if it changed your manual edition?

Comment: we were doing a little mistake